# How to change the color of only one specific button in BaseAdapter?

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-button, baseadapter

I have a problem namely in my BaseAdapter I try to change the color of the button only for specific letters that I find in them, but when I try to do it, the color changes all buttons in the system, what can I do?

More specifically, in the MainActivity class I have two lists:
userAnswer and newList. When creating a class in onCreate (), I add certain letters A, B, C etc. to the userAnswer. and I would like to add next letters to userAnswer after choosing buttonAddLetter, only I want to make these new letters change color to another one and not to the same as the other ones. Everything works, however, the problem is that all letters change to a different color, although in BaseAdapter I check if the data comes from newList, if so, change the color. What am I doing wrong? Why is the color changing for all buttons?

Thank you for your help.

**GridViewAnswerAdapter.class**

```
public class GridViewAnswerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<String> answer;
private Context context;
private MainActivity mainActivity;

public GridViewAnswerAdapter(List<String> answer, Context context, MainActivity mainActivity) {
    this.answer = answer;
    this.context = context;
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return answer.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return answer.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Button buttonAnswerAdapter = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        if (answer.get(position).equals(" ")) {

            buttonAnswerAdapter = new Button(context);
            buttonAnswerAdapter.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            buttonAnswerAdapter.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            buttonAnswerAdapter.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        }

//I want to change color button only where newList add some new letter, //everything is ok, but it's change every button colors, why?

        else if(mainActivity.newList.size() != 0){

            if (mainActivity.newList.get(position).equals(answer.get(position))) {

                buttonAnswerAdapter = new Button(context);
                buttonAnswerAdapter.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
                buttonAnswerAdapter.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                buttonAnswerAdapter.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                buttonAnswerAdapter.setTextColor(Color.RED);


                buttonAnswerAdapter.setText(String.valueOf(mainActivity.newList.get(position)));
            }
        }

        else if(mainActivity.userAnswer.get(position).equals(answer.get(position))) {

            //Create new button
            buttonAnswerAdapter = new Button(context);
            buttonAnswerAdapter.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            buttonAnswerAdapter.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            buttonAnswerAdapter.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);


            buttonAnswerAdapter.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);


            buttonAnswerAdapter.setText(String.valueOf(answer.get(position)));

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Something is wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
        else {
            buttonAnswerAdapter = (Button) convertView;
        }

    return buttonAnswerAdapter;
}
```

}

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


List<String> userAnswer = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();

GridViewAnswerAdapter gridViewAnswerAdapter;
GridView gridViewAnswer;

Button buttonAddLetter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridViewAnswer = findViewById(R.id.gridViewAnswer);
    buttonAddLetter = findViewById(R.id.buttonWskazówka);


    buttonAddLetter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addMore();
        }
    });


    userAnswer.add(0, "A");
    userAnswer.add(1, "B");
    userAnswer.add(2, "C");
    userAnswer.add(3, "D");
    userAnswer.add(4, "E");
    userAnswer.add(5, "F");
    userAnswer.add(6, "G");


    gridViewAnswerAdapter = new GridViewAnswerAdapter(userAnswer, getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.this);
    gridViewAnswer.setAdapter(gridViewAnswerAdapter);

    gridViewAnswerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

private void addMore()
{

    newList.clear();

    newList.addAll(userAnswer);
    newList.set(0, "A");
    newList.set(1, "B");
    newList.set(2, "C");


    gridViewAnswerAdapter = new GridViewAnswerAdapter(userAnswer, getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.this);
    gridViewAnswer.setAdapter(gridViewAnswerAdapter);

    gridViewAnswerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

}

**I add pictures because I do not know how to fully explain what I would like to achieve:**

On 1 picture I have a list view with 6 buttons, on the second picture we have a list (new List, which adds 0,1,2 - A, B, C on the index) of buttons in only a different color. The problem is that I would like to achieve the result from the 3rd picture, i.e. when I press the sock I want the newly added letters to have a completely different color and the ones that have already been in the color that it was.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZrJd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaUop.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfUtW.png)

Comment: You asked this [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981855/how-to-change-text-color-on-button-in-baseadapter)  yesterday:: I did not understand what you wanted then and this slightly altered question statement has not made it any more clearer what it is you are trying to achieve. Two suggestions: (1) write out a question statement in your native language and use Google Translate to English. (2) and/or make some images of what you wish to achieve and post that with your question. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I added this question, but in a different form, because I was afraid it was wrong and perhaps it would be difficult to understand. As you can see, I was right. I edited the question and added pictures to it which I would like to do. I hope that this time I managed to explain it a bit better.

Comment: It really isn't a good idea to pass the `Activity` to the `ListView` in order to access any object local to the `Activity`. But since `List` "userAnswer" is the bases for the `List` "answer" would this statement `mainActivity.userAnswer.get(position).equals(answer.get(position))` always be true??

Comment: I would like this statement to always be true, because the same letter will be matched exactly to the same button.
I want to achieve this effect, then to prevent the user from choosing a button that is from the new list, and under this color, I can just go wrong completely and it can be done completely differently than through the baseAdapter.

Comment: I am writing a similar game to this one:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lemmingsatwork.quiz
maybe this will bring me even closer to what I mean. When you select a hint button, a letter that is matched to a particular squeeze changes its color and you can no longer choose or remove it from that list. This is the effect I want, so I try to distinguish the letters in the buttons with colors to prevent the user from selecting this button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Adapter` constructor and pass the `List` "newList"  directly to the `Adapter`. It isn't a good idea to pass the `Activity` just so you can access some class variable that is in your `Activity`.

```
private List<String> answer;
private List<String> newList;
private Context context;

public GridViewAnswerAdapter(List<String> answer, List<String> newList, Context context) {
    this.answer = answer;
    this.newList = newList;
    this.context = context;
}
```

Use this from your `MainActivity`:

```
gridViewAnswerAdapter = new GridViewAnswerAdapter(userAnswer, newList, MainActivity.this);
```

Change the `getView()`method of your `Adapter` to this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Button buttonAnswerAdapter = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        buttonAnswerAdapter = new Button(context);
        buttonAnswerAdapter.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        buttonAnswerAdapter.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        buttonAnswerAdapter.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        buttonAnswerAdapter.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        buttonAnswerAdapter.setText(answer.get(position));
    }else{
        buttonAnswerAdapter = (Button) convertView;
    }

    if(newList.size() != 0){
        if (newList.get(position).equals(answer.get(position))) {
            buttonAnswerAdapter.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            buttonAnswerAdapter.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }

    return buttonAnswerAdapter;
}
```

In your `addMore()` method there is no need to have this:

```
gridViewAnswerAdapter = new GridViewAnswerAdapter(userAnswer, getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.this);
gridViewAnswer.setAdapter(gridViewAnswerAdapter);
```

because the `Adapter` is already set and the "newList" has already been added.

I would usually use my own custom xml layout for the `View` that I would `inflate` in my `ListView`. But, if just creating a `Button` works for you..why not?

Comment: Everything works correctly Thank you very much for your help.
I have one more question if there are 2 lists in the adapter:
   public GridViewAnswerAdapter (List <String> answer, List <String> newList, Context context, MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.answer = answer;
        this.newList = newList;
        this.context = context;
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

 in the getCount method, we always return the length of only one, can we use the other?

 @Override
    public int getCount () {
       return answer.size ();
    }

Comment: You can override the method to return the length of the list you want to use.

Comment: Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having a very hard time understanding you're desired result. If you want to change the button color after initialising store a reference to either the button adapter or the button directly. That way you can just access it during runtime and change it to whatever you desire.

Comment: This is the problem of how to get this effect if I create buttons dynamically in BaseAdapter. That is, we create all the buttons dynamically, so how can we distinguish the newly added list in the adapter so that only newly added buttons with letters change their color?